# when I add another <li> to my <ul> it appears outside the container all the way at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list ul with a li inside it and when I add another li inside the ul it drops to the bottom of the page and is outside the parent div containing it, however the div has more than enough height to contain the li's and its meant to be directly below the other li any help would be appreciated thank you, I know its probably something simple that I'm missing

```
 <div class="username-review">
              <ul class="review-fields">
                <li class="review-content">
              <div class="review" clearfix>
                <div class="review-user-profile" clearfix>
                  <div class="profile-picture" clearfix>
                  </div>      
                    <div class="username">
                    <a href="usersname" class="usersname"> <span>Username</span></a> 
                    </div>
                   
                  <span class="users-review-overall-stars">
                      <i class="fas fa-star"></i> 
                      <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                      <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                      <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                      <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                  </span>  
                  <div class="review-title-container">
                    <span class="review-title">Perfect item</span>
                  </div>  
                </div>
    
                <div class="users-review-info"> <!-- display the first 10 reviews and then have a see all reviews button -->
                  <p>Very good game perfect for beginners aswell as experienced players, great graphics and amazing content.</p>
                  <a class="user-review-actions" href="#">Like</a>
                  <a>&#124;</a>
                  <a class="user-review-actions" href="#">Dislike</a> 
                  <a>&#124;</a>
                  <a class="user-review-actions" href="#">Report</a>  
                </div>                        
              </div>
              
              <a class="see-all-reviews" href="#">See all reviews</a> 
            </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>  



.username-review {
  position: relative;
  width: 1050px;
  height: 990px;
  bottom: 1200px;
  left: 370px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.review-fields {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 170px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.review-content {
  list-style: none;
  height: 170px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid orangered;
}

.review {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.review-user-profile {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.profile-picture {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid orangered;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: 40px;
  left: 30px;
}

.username {
 position: relative;
 left: 90px; 
 top: 6px;
}

.usersname  {
  color: #fd886b;
}

.usersname:hover  {
  color: orangered;
}

.users-review-overall-stars {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 45px;
}

.review-title {
  position: relative;
  
}

.review-title-container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 37px;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.users-review-info {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 842px;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 200px;
  left: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.users-review-info p {
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  left: 10px;
}

.users-review-info a {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: #fd886b;
}

.users-review-info a:hover {
  color: orangered;
}

.see-all-reviews {
  position: relative;
  top: 730px;
  left: 475px;
  color: #fd886b;
}

.see-all-reviews:hover {
  color: orangered;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra, unnecessary `</div>` above your `</li>` which is corrupting the DOM tree. You should use an HTML linter within your editor.